# Ruby specifying regexp

Tags: ruby, regex

How would I write a *regexp* so that the string MUST equal the exact format in the regexp?

*For example:*

```
/\d:\d/ =~ 5:4
```

*BUT*

```
/\d:\d/ is also equal to 5:42alskjf2425
```

how do I make it so that my *regexp* checks for only a digit, followed by a colon, followed by a digit, and nothing else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Use `\A` and `\z` [anchors](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors), to match the beginning and end of a string:

```
/\A\d:\d\z/ =~ '5:4'  # => 0   (boolean true)
/\A\d:\d\z/ =~ '5:4x' # => nil (boolean false)
```

Comment: @user3329470 - if the answer is what you're looking for you can accept it by clicking the check mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to specify how many characters must be found, you can do it a couple ways:

- `\d` finds one.
- `\d{1}` finds one.
- `\d{1,2}` finds one or two.
- `\d{1,}` finds one or more.
- `\d{,2}` finds zero, one or two.

In other words, use:

```
/\d{1}:\d{1}/
```

Check it out:

```
'5:4'[/\d{1}:\d{1}/]             # => "5:4"
'5:42alskjf2425'[/\d{1}:\d{1}/]  # => "5:4"
```

That's all documented so take the time to read through the [Regexp documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html).